# error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

[image]I am also facing a same issue while running the react-native app. The version i am using is as follows:

React-Native:0.57.1
react-native-cli:2.0.1
node:v8.11.3
npm:5.6.0

Babel Version details:

> "devDependencies": { "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0", "babel-jest": "20.0.3", "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0", "jest": "20.0.4", "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12", "schedule": "^0.4.0" }, "jest": { "preset": "react-native" } }

Error:

> error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of
>   null
>       at Scope.moveBindingTo (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:867:13)
>       at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:364:17)
>       at BlockScoping.run (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:330:12)
>       at PluginPass.BlockStatementSwitchStatementProgram (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:70:24)
>       at newFn (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
>       at NodePath._call (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
>       at NodePath.call (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
>       at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/manish/Desktop/Practice/donut/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
>   BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.android.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0%
>   (0/3)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Oct/2018:05:31:17 +0000] "GET
>   /index.android.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1"
>   500 - "-" "okhttp/3.10.0"  BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.android.js
>   ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/3), failed.

It seems as if error is coming due to babel. But not able to get the solution. What is the solution for this issue ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just cloned my project from repository and tried to run it but it  showed error. After making some changes i am still getting this error.

Comment: What is the version of Babel? Is that compatible with typescript and reactnative version?

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using `babel-preset-react-native` in dependency which has been deprecated instead "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.47.0" is now being used. So, I updated this in `.babelrc` file and I added the below line:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

The above code resolved the issue.